# Laravel by default prefixing the result with a "php" string

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

Whenever I'm trying to return a view from views in Laravel, it is adding "Php" as a prefix. It also happens when I am returning JSON using Ajax.

E.g., I am returning array `("data"=> "success")` in a .php file, but while printing the result, it displays `php{"data":"success"}`.

Is this a problem with Laravel or do some settings have to be done?

Comment: Can you show us the php file in total?

Answer (score 1):

In one of your files somewhere you probably have mistyped "php" at the top of the file before the `php` opening tag.

Comment: i checked all the files and i am getting this  while hitting a ajax request also.